# Is it possible to have different pinned app tabs per tab group?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, session-manager

I have Firefox 10 and I want to have 2 main group of tabs. My personal tabs, with pinned tabs like my personal gmail, facebook, etc. And another group of tabs for my work, with pinned tabs like my work email and other sites.

- Is it possible to have different pinned tabs between tab groups?
- Or do I have to use some Session Manager? If so, which one do you recommend?

Comment: I would like the same feature. I have not found a plugin that can do this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Tile Tabs add-on which allows you to organize tabs into tiled layouts? Tile tabs keeps functionality no matter what group of tabs you are working in. You can rearrange your tiles horizontally or vertically or in a grid whichever is most efficient for your workflow. For example I have tabs for client requests, my admin work, communications and IT research. This works very well for jumping from function to function.